# Error1706 Registry error for Windows XP Small Business installation...Can't remove pop up window for installation

Tags: windows, windows-xp

This is an old computer I inherited from my dad.  I don't have the CD for Windows XP Small Business but the pop up window keeps coming up saying insert CD, but its already installed.

How do I stop the pop up window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it Office for Small Business? Is there a program in add/remove programs list that matches?, if so try to uninstall it there if you don't need the program.

If not, post a comment and I will post another solution

Comment: It's Small Business.  The operating system is Windows XP Professional  but the pop up is for Windows XP Small Business.  I have tried to unistall the small business and it doesn't want to do it? Any ideas? Under the programs it has both the Windows XP professional 97 and the small business xp.

Comment: we got it! that seem to work with another pack we found. Thanks again